# libicuuc.so.48, needed by libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qmake

I got this warning when trying to run via QtCreator the programm which worked previously.
Also I got this warning: 
`libicui18n.so.48, needed by /home/maxim/install/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)` 
and (from libQt5Core.so) a dozen errors like: 
`/home/maxim/install/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so:-1: error: undefined reference to ucnv_fromUnicode_48'` 

This problems appeared just **after Ubuntu upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04**. How can I fix this? Also I trying to install libicu48

```
maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libicu48
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu48 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu48' has no installation candidate
```

Other variants libicu (libicu48, libicu52-dbg, libicu4j-4.4-java, libicu52, libicu-dev) alredy installed but I got same warnings. 
 When I just run any qt programm (e.g. from terminal) I got this: ./anyprogramm: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you built Qt yourself? Why don't you just use the packages from your distribution? In any case, with custom sysroot when building, you will need to add [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28094).

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, I built qt from the sources. What exactly do I need to?

Comment: Have you read the link pasted? `A solution would be: Add -licudata to unix:LIBS variable in qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.pro.` Let me know if that works, and I will submit it as an answer.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I still don't understand :( I found icu.pro - okay. It's contains: `SOURCES = icu.cpp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt dylib
win32 {
    CONFIG(static, static|shared) {
        CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
            LIBS += -lsicuind -lsicuucd -lsicudtd
        } else {
            LIBS += -lsicuin -lsicuuc -lsicudt
        }
    } else {
        LIBS += -licuin -licuuc
    }
} else {
    LIBS += -licui18n -licuuc
}` where I should place -licudata and what's next?

Comment: It is not that difficult. :) Unix means not win32 here, so add it in the else branch.

Comment: @LaszloPapp okay, but what I should do after this?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Oh... rly? All over again?

Comment: Haven't I already told to use the binary packages from Ubuntu?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I added -licudata, I tried to rebuild Qt with the same configure options that I have used previously, but every time I got a variety of errors and in the end I gave up and downloaded the precompiled libraries :(

Comment: @LaszloPapp, as you see fit. At least reinstall certainly works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use the binary packages from your distribution, but if you insist on custom builds and custom rpaths, you need to apply the fix [in this ticket on Jira](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28094):

> A solution would be: Add -licudata to unix:LIBS variable in qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.pro.